# How to specify path to C libraries in jspin?

Tags: mingw, spin, promela

I am using jspin and trying to include stdio.h library within c_code expression:

```
c_code
{
    #include <stdio.h>
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
spin: error: No file 'stdio.h'
```

I have checked directory where mingw is installed and it has stdio.h inside. Thus, I suppose, it is all about wrong paths. How can I set include path in jspin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
c_decl {
  \#include <stdio.h>
}
```

The `\#` is the critical part ([Spinroot.com for c_decl](http://bit.ly/12B7SIf)).  Also, use `c_decl{}` because `.h` files contain no code.

[edit] Regarding fprintf() not showing output; I can't say I know the reason.  I tried your particular code.  Here is the result:

```
ebg@ebg$ rm /tmp/foo.bar
ebg@ebg$ spin -a test.pml
ebg@ebg$ gcc -o test pan.c
ebg@ebg$ ./test
hint: this search is more efficient if pan.c is compiled -DSAFETY

(Spin Version 6.2.4 -- 21 November 2012)
    + Partial Order Reduction

Full statespace search for:
    never claim             - (none specified)
    assertion violations    +
    acceptance   cycles     - (not selected)
    invalid end states  +

State-vector 12 byte, depth reached 2, errors: 0
        3 states, stored
        0 states, matched
        3 transitions (= stored+matched)
        0 atomic steps
hash conflicts:         0 (resolved)

Stats on memory usage (in Megabytes):
    0.000   equivalent memory usage for states (stored*(State-vector + overhead))
    0.292   actual memory usage for states
  128.000   memory used for hash table (-w24)
    0.534   memory used for DFS stack (-m10000)
  128.730   total actual memory usage


unreached in init
    (0 of 2 states)

pan: elapsed time 0 seconds
ebg@ebg$ cat /tmp/foo.bar 
some str
```

Here is the code I used:

```
c_decl {
  \#include <stdio.h>
}

init {
  c_code {
    FILE *file;

    file = fopen ("/tmp/foo.bar", "a+");
    fprintf (file, "%s", "some str");
    fclose (file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Backslash really did the trick. However, my C code does not work... I want to write some info into a file, so i write:

`FILE *file; 
file = fopen("C:\\file.txt","a+"); 
fprintf(file,"%s","some str"); 
fclose(file);`

but nothing happens.. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Is that all in one c_code{} statement?  If so, it should work.  If not, you would need to `c_track` the `file` value (so that it is not lost during backtracking).  Note that printing output during a verification can have unexpected results because of the exhaustive search.

Comment: See edit above.  I produced a simple `.pml` file with your `file` C-code.  It seems to work.

Comment: Thanks! I was running the model with Random button instead of Verify one, that's why it did not work. It still seems strange to me, that a random trace does not execute C code, but it is not that important, since I obviously need full verification.